# Can Sencha Touch consume JSON Schema definitions generated by JSON.NET?

Tags: .net, wcf, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, json.net

We currently have a .NET WCF Web Service with JSON as the response and request format.  With every build, we generate and publish the JSON Schema files (via JSON.NET) for every entity that gets serialized/deserialized.

If you've never seen JSON Schema files, they are in the following format:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Id": {
      "required": true,
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "Name": {
      "required": true,
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    "Email": {
      "required": true,
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way for Sencha Touch to easily consume these generated files and use them as a model?

Comment: I don't think that is one by one the correct model definition Sencha uses. But it shouldn't be too hard to come up with a script that does the necessary transformation.

Answer (score 0):

you can write your own Data-Reader. So, you can parse and transform every data you want.

[data.reader api docs (sencha touch 2)](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader)

Comment: I don't think that this is what he wants. I think he wants to keep the sencha side models in sync with the server side models. So everytime the serverside model changes the sencha model should change accordingly. That's at least how I understand it.